# No OK button in recovery mode on MyPhone Agua Rio Fun

Tags: rooting, recovery-mode, buttons

I bought a new smartphone, [MyPhone Agua Rio Fun](http://www.pinoytechblog.com/archives/myphone-rio-fun-5-inch-android-smartphone-priced-at-php-2999) (a local brand in Philippines). It's actually a pretty good phone in my book, but the storage in this thing is terrible! I found a way to solve it, but it says I have to root my phone.

I used to have Samsung Galaxy Pocket and I had no trouble rooting it. However, on Rio Fun, the only solid keys are volume up/down and the power buttons. When I try to go to recovery mode, it doesn't let me select anything! It doesn't have a solid home button, only the soft Home, Menu and Back keys (which can't be used when in recovery mode!). The power button just shows the triangle Android (!) sign then the recovery menu again! (any other root methods don't work on it!)

How can I navigate in recovery mode with this phone, and how can I root this phone?

Comment: Usually the Volume buttons are used to navigate up and down, and Power is used to select. Are you saying this does not work for your recovery? Do you have the Stock recovery? What version of Android is on the device?

Comment: No, the volumeupdown ad power button are the only physical buttons. the rest are soft keys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also have the same kind of phone (MP Rio Fun) and I am trying to partition my SD. In the Recovery mode, you have to use the volume keys/button to highlight the option that you want then you have to press the Option key (the key on the left side of the Home key) to enter the highlighted option. 
Hope this help.

Comment: Finally, my prayers Have been answered! Thanks for the help, Mate!

Answer (score 0):

Recovery menus usually don't have *any* touch elements, you only control them using hardware keys (otherwise you'd be lost with a broken digitizer when trying to backup your data). Use the <kbd>volume</kbd> keys (up/down) to navigate, and the <kbd>power</kbd> button to select an item.

Comment: Yeah,but the problem is the Power Button only shows the recovery menu and when pressed again its shows the !android Screen.i have no other Hard Buttons but the volumes :(

Comment: Umm, then I'm at a loss. I know on some HTC devices, you can use the trackball instead – but if your device has no such, that's out again. Only thing I can think of then (apart from calling the manufacturer's service to ask) is installing a custom recovery (if there's one available for the device).

Comment: I've tried using these MediaTek devices and usually their select button is Volume Down and their scrolling button is Volume Up (only one direction). Try that to see if it works.

Comment: @aureljared;the volume buttons are directional,volume up is up and volume down is down:(

Comment: Just guessing now (try-and-err), but we've got no other chance: What if you keep the volume button pressed? Does it continue to scroll, or maybe select the next item? // For a definite answer, I'd strongly suggest to ask their service staff. They should know.